# using thread to run a method

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

I need to use thread to run a `SlowFileStringifier.display()` method. I have created a Proxy class to run  `public void display(PrintWriter out)` method present in `SlowFileStringifier` class.

The program reads files present inside data folder and displays the output.

The proxy `display(PrintWriter out)` should output some text right away, then it should start a thread to run the `SlowFileStringifier.display()` method.

Below is the output I want:

```
Reading data\anaisnin.txt
Reading data\cree.txt
Reading data\maewest.txt
Reading data\marktwain.txt
Reading data\rumi.txt
"Whenever you find yourself on the side of the majority, it is time to pause and reflect."
- Mark Twain
"You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough."- Mae West
"If you are irritated by every rub, how will your mirror be polished?"
- Jalaluddin Mevlana Rumi
"There came a time when the risk to remain tight in the bud was more painful than the risk it took to blossom."
- Anais Nin
```

Below are my classes:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class FileStringifierProxy implements FileStringifier{

    private final String fileName;

    public FileStringifierProxy(String filename) {
        this.fileName = filename;
}


    @Override
    public void display(PrintWriter out) {
        System.out.println("Reading "+fileName);
        SlowFileStringifier slowfilestringifier = new SlowFileStringifier(fileName);
        slowfilestringifier.display(out);
    }


    @Override
    public String stringify() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



}

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Simple file reader that turns a file into a string
 */
public class SlowFileStringifier implements FileStringifier {

    /**
     * Create a file stringifier with a file name
     * 
     * @param filename
     *            file name of file
     */
    public SlowFileStringifier(String filename) {
        this.fileName = filename;
    }

    /**
     * Writes out the file contents to the print writer
     * 
     * @param out
     *            the output print writer
     */
    public void display(PrintWriter out) {
        out.println(this.stringify());
        out.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string with all the files contents
     */
    public String stringify() {
        FileReader f;
        try {
            f = new FileReader(this.fileName);
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(f);

            ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                lines.add(line);
            }
            bf.close();
            return String.join("\n", lines);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("File " + this.fileName + " was not found.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Problem reading file " + this.fileName + ".");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("File reading interrupted: " + this.fileName);
        }
        return "";
    }

    private final String fileName;
}

public class ShowFileContents {

    /**
     * Accepts a file directory and then prints out the contents of all the
     * files in that directory
     * 
     * @param args
     *            single arg with directory path
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java ShowFileContents <directory>");
        }

        String dirname = args[0];

        File dir = new File(dirname);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            System.err.println(dirname + " does not exist");
            return;
        }
        if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
            System.err.println(dirname + " is not a directory");
            return;
        }

        PrintWriter outWriter = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isDirectory())
                continue;
            FileStringifier fd = new FileStringifierProxy(file.getPath());
            fd.display(outWriter);
        }
    }

}
```

Below is the output I am getting right now:

```
Reading data\anaisnin.txt
"There came a time when the risk to remain tight in the bud was more painful than the risk it took to blossom."
- Anais Nin
Reading data\cree.txt
"When all the trees have been cut down, when all the animals have been hunted, when all the waters are polluted, when all the air is unsafe to breathe, only then will you discover you cannot eat money."
- Cree Prophecy
Reading data\maewest.txt
"You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough."
- Mae West
Reading data\marktwain.txt
"Whenever you find yourself on the side of the majority, it is time to pause and reflect."
- Mark Twain
Reading data\rumi.txt
"If you are irritated by every rub, how will your mirror be polished?"
- Jalaluddin Mevlana Rumi
```

Comment: And what is happening instead?

Comment: Consider using a CountDownLatch

Comment: You don't seem to be using new thread to run through the contents of your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CountDownLatch(suggested by [@Xingbin Sun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6690200/xingbin-sun)) and CyclicBarrier. both provides the way of thread synchronization. 
In your case you want threads to wait for finish writing name then proceed to content.

To deal with your specific problem here is the code you may want to go through.

Your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.out.println("Usage: java ShowFileContents <directory>");
    }

    String dirname = args[0];

    File dir = new File(dirname);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        System.err.println(dirname + " does not exist");
        return;
    }
    if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
        System.err.println(dirname + " is not a directory");
        return;
    }

    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    int noOfFilesToProcess = 0;
    for (final File file : files) {
        if (!file.isDirectory()) {
            noOfFilesToProcess++;
        }
    }
    final CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(noOfFilesToProcess);
    final PrintWriter outWriter = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    for (final File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory())
            continue;
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                FileStringifier fd = new FileStringifierProxy(
                        file.getPath(), startSignal, doneSignal);
                fd.display(outWriter);
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
    // Do something here
    startSignal.countDown(); // let all threads proceed
    // Do something here while other threads are processing
    try {
        doneSignal.await(); // wait for all to finish
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Do something after all thread finishes
}
```

Implementation of FileStringifierProxy:

```
class FileStringifierProxy implements FileStringifier {

    private final String fileName;
    private final CountDownLatch startSignal;
    private final CountDownLatch doneSignal;

    public FileStringifierProxy(String filename, CountDownLatch startSignal,
        CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
        this.fileName = filename;
        this.startSignal = startSignal;
        this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
    }

    public void display(final PrintWriter out) {
        System.out.println("Reading " + fileName);
        final SlowFileStringifier slowfilestringifier = new 
 SlowFileStringifier(
            fileName);
        try {
            startSignal.await(); // Wait for start signal from main thread
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        slowfilestringifier.display(out); // Display file content
        doneSignal.countDown(); // Send done signal to main thread
    }

    public String stringify() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
 }
```